# Refused to apply style from 'loca.."' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

[image: Router definition]

I try to load index.html file..this index.html contains a lot of css and js file..

[image: Page Screenshot]

but only load only index.html file not load css and js files.. i got some console error (Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/dashboard/css.6777faf8.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled)

I try a different browser it does not work.
[image]

Comment: How do you server the static content(js, css files)? If you type *http://localhost/dashboard/css.6777faf8.css* into browser address bar what do you see? Is it the actual css file or something else?

Comment: i see 404 error

Comment: So i ask once more *How do you server the static content(js, css files)*? Do you use express-static middleware maybe? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: sir this my first experience in coding .. i attach my index.html file

Comment: Well if this is your first experience in coding then you should read/watch some tutorials on how things work in Node.js. I asked you twice how you serve static files and you haven't answered. It's realy hard to help.